# Downloading multiple attachments from a mail in outlook using R

Tags: r, outlook, automation

How to download multiple attachments (all are CSVs) using R from outlook?

My code is just reading the first attachment. I am unable to iterate over all the attachments present in the mail.

used RDCOMClient as the library

```
library(RDCOMClient)

outlook_app <- COMCreate("Outlook.Application")


search <- outlook_app$AdvancedSearch(
  "Inbox",
  "urn:schemas:httpmail:subject = 'test'"
)

Sys.sleep(5)
results <- search$Results()

Sys.sleep(10)

results$Item(1)$ReceivedTime() # Received time of first search result

as.Date("1899-12-30") + floor(results$Item(1)$ReceivedTime()) # Received date

for (i in 1:results$Count()) {
  print(i)
  if (as.Date("1899-12-30") + floor(results$Item(i)$ReceivedTime())  == as.Date("2019-04-03")) {
      email <- results$Item(i)
  }
}

attachment_file <- tempfile()

email$Attachments(1)$SaveAsFile(attachment_file)


data <- read.csv(attachment_file)
```

Unable to save attachments apart from the first one.

Comment: I don't even understand the syntax properly, but doesn't this `email$Attachments(1)$SaveAsFile` just refer to the fist item? There's no saving in the loop...

Comment: Actually mail has 4 attachments but results$Count() is giving only 1 and that's why email$Attachments(1)$SaveAsFile is not working ,if i change 1 to 2,3 or 4 @JamesZ

Answer (score 0):

I have been able to extract multiple attached files with the following code :

```
library(RDCOMClient)
OutApp <- COMCreate("Outlook.Application")
outlookNameSpace <- OutApp$GetNameSpace("MAPI")

dir_Attached_Files <- "D:\\"
setwd(dir_Attached_Files)
msg_Files <- list.files()
nb_Files <- length(msg_Files)

list_Attached_Files <- list()
destination_dir <- "D:\\"

for(j in 1 : nb_Files)
{
  path_msg <- paste0(dir_Attached_Files, msg_Files[j])
  message <- outlookNameSpace$OpenSharedItem(path_msg)
  nb_Attached_Files <- message$Attachments()$Count()
  
  for(i in 1 : nb_Attached_Files)
  {
    print(i)
    attachment_file <- paste0(destination_dir, message$Attachments(i)$Filename())
    message$Attachments(i)$SaveAsFile(attachment_file)
    Sys.sleep(3)
  }
}
```